# if a class type is parameter of a function which is called by value, will the overloaded assignment operator of  the class get called?

Tags: c++, function, overloading

Let `A` be class with overloaded `operator=`
If I call a function that has a parameter `A` by value, Will the overloaded `operator=` called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No its assignment operator won't be called.
The copy constructor will be called.

That is the purpose of copy constructor, to create copies of the type by taking in an object of the same type. Pass by value is the typical case where copy constructor is always called.